# How to compare values between two columns with custom logic IF statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i have table like this, How do i compare this simple value with `IF` statement

i want to compare j_path column's value with j_foto's value based on their s_username, IF j_path's value and j_foto's value SAME, then the score column would be same, example in admin: is 8.

IF j_path's value and j_foto's value NOT THE SAME, then the score column would be j_foto.
sorry for my beginner, appreciate your help. thanks

[image]

Comment: As I understand - you want to copy the value of `j_foto` into the `score`. So where is the problem? Don't you know how to write an UPDATE statement?

Comment: i didn't think that way before. but i'll go delete this question if not take as proportion as problem, forgive sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, your rules reduce to just using the value in `j_foto`:

```
update t
    set score = j_foto;
```

Conditional logic is not needed for what you describe.

You may have the situation where `j_foto` is `NULL` and in that case you might want `j_path` (although this situation is not mentioned in the question nor suggested by the data).  In that case, use `coalesce()`:

```
update t
    set score = coalesce(j_foto, j_path);
```

Comment: yes, correct, it might be null, and it might be lots of number too, that's concern me, i'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: the situation you mention happen sir, at more data input, yes. thank you sir. and to ALL who already see this post.